# My notification panel and home button not working. It's saying developer options not available for this use when i checked the developer options

Tags: notification-bar, developer-options

My android device(Asus max pro m2) is running on havoc(3.2) suddenly rebooted and I cannot use my notification panel, home button, or literally anything else. This issue will be solved if I delete the data partition using TWRP but. I have to literally install every application again and again. Nova launcher method not working for me. I tried everything regarding that nova launcher thing but no use. if I check the developer options it says developer options not available for this user. This isn't the first time this issue happened. but earlier I had to reset the things. but now I would like to know if there is any other solution to this. Anyone, please respond asap. cause I couldn't use my phone if I cant get a solution.
Thank you in advance

Comment: For the time being use https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.treydev.micontrolcenter&hl=en&gl=US and https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nu.nav.bar&hl=en&gl=US until you get a solution. Don't reset that's a very tedious and annoying thing to do

Comment: Is there any permanent solution to this issue..?

Comment: Give these a try.. https://www.digitbin.com/cant-pull-notification-not-working/ And what do you mean by when i checked the developer options? What is it saying and what did you check.. please clarify

Comment: BEFORE THOSE try this.. Go to settings - users - switch to "guest" - switch back to "owner".

Comment: Developer options means settings>system>developer options. If I click that developer options it says Developer options are not available for this user. And regarding that guest mode, u suggested. I cant click that multiple user options. When I click the multiple users option nothing happens.

Comment: There is something weird with the users on your device. Can you see in which user you are somewhere? Developer options are only available for the Owner (the main user). And do you have any work profile active in Settings>Accounts? Which os are you on? and android version?